# How do I load an image from an URL (that has a different origin) into a File object?

Tags: javascript, image, blob

At first I thought it should be as easy as:

```
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = () => { ... }
img.onerror = () => { ... }
img.src = url;
```

But then it turned out I need to draw it on a canvas, then `toBlob()`. And don't forget to **add CORS** and `crossorigin="anonymous"` to the `img` tag. Isn't it a bit too involved? Is there a better way?

To show you the final solution (you need CORS headers):

```
function getFileFromURL(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const fileName = url.split('/').pop();
        const img = document.createElement('img');
        img.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
        img.onload = () => {
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            canvas.toBlob(blob => {
                resolve(new File([blob], fileName));
            });
        };
        img.onerror = () => {
            reject('something went wrong');
        };
        img.src = url;
    })
}
```

Comment: Well you could request the actual image data using AJAX ... but then you won't get away with `crossorigin="anonymous"` any more, the remote party would have to actively support proper CORS then.

Comment: if you just want to display an image, cors shouldnt be an issue, but if you are trying to access the data of the image, like scanning pixels etc. Do you have an example?

Comment: @CBroe With my solution I also need to add CORS. Without them it doesn't work.

Comment: @Skarlinski I need to access the data.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, `anonymous` just prevents sending of credentials, but the image must have been CORS enabled already, otherwise trying to export it from canvas would have failed to begin with ("tainted canvas".) So - AJAX request for the image URL, and then feed the result of that to the `File` constructor ...?

Comment: Does this "final solution" work?

Comment: @MontanaBurr Yep.

Comment: "Is there a better way?" Yes, it's called [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @x-yuri note It will only work when the server has allow-origin for your domain

Comment: Yep, I said in the question that I added CORS. | @MontanaBurr I think "Website" is too vague. Are `http://example.com` and `https://example.com` different sites? They're certainly different origins.

Comment: @x-yuri Since the domain names are the same -- no, they're the same site.

Comment: In any case, if what's causing the error is that you're browsing https:// your-site.com and you're requesting the image from http:// your-site.com, the solution seems obvious - have the browser download the image from https:// your-site.com.

Comment: @MontanaBurr What about `http://mymomssite.mycompany.com`, `http://mycompany.com:3000`, `http://mycompany.com`, `https://mycompany.com`? I mean generally "website" will do, but occasionally [the details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#definition_of_an_origin) matter. Like, when talking about CORS. P.S. How do you know what schemes I use? It's the other way around the page uses http://, and the image is from https://. And it works, but I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: @x-yuri If you can configure the Webserver of the site the image is on, another possible solution would be to configure the Webserver to pass the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header along with the image, like so: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: (insert either * for all origins or the URL of the requesting origin)

Comment: @MontanaBurr Let me repeat it the third time on this page. I'm adding CORS. My solution doesn't work without CORS. The fourth if we take the question into consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution suggested by CBroe is arguably better:

```
function getFileFromURL(url) {
    const fileName = url.split('/').pop();
    return fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            return new File([response.data], fileName);
        });
}
```

Make sure you add CORS headers to the request(s).